# Создать route в Kohana framework

Tags: kohana-3

Пишу route

```
    Route::set('sitemap', 'sitemap')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'seomap'));
```

Хочу стучаться в Controller: index, Action: action_seomap

Что делаю не правильно?

Версия framework 3.1.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
Route::set('sitemap', 'sitemap')
        ->defaults(array(
            'directory'  => 'Sitemap',
            'controller' => 'Map',
            'action'     => 'Index',
        ));
```

При данном route, контролер должен находится по данному адресу
application/classes/Controller/Sitemap/Map.php

```
<?php class Controller_Sitemap_Map extends Controller_Template {
public function action_Index() {
```

В вашем случае, контролер должен находится 
application/classes/Controller/Sitemap.php
Так же надо учесть что объявление нового роута должно быть раньше, роута который может его заменить.

```html
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
  ->defaults([
   'controller' => 'Home',
   'action'     => 'HelloWord',
  ]);
    
// sitemap - Не будет отрабатывать так как с начало выполниться роут default
Route::set('sitemap', 'sitemap')
            ->defaults(array(
                'controller' => 'Seomap',
                'action'     => 'Index',
            ));
```

Вам нужно посмотреть не блокирует "другой роут", ваш.